# vc++ 2010/2012: std::vector of a struct containing unique_ptr compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, c++11, unique-ptr

The following code generates the compiler error below (after the code), but not if the vector contains unique_ptr's directly (see commented code lines). Any ideas why?

The question is more concerned with the code block in the "#if 1" block, the "#else" block generates the error (after changing "#if 1" to "#if 0") that is similar, but is more expected.

```
// MoveSemantics.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef std::unique_ptr<int> upi;

struct S
{
    S() : p(new int(123)) {}
    S(S&& s) : p( std::move(s.p) ) {} // NB: the move constructor is supposed to be used? (but not)
    upi p;
};

#if 1
void test()
{
    //std::vector<S> vs; // Okay
    //std::vector<upi> vupi(10); // Okay
    std::vector<S> vs(10); // Error! why in the hell does the compiler want to generate a copy constructor here??
}
#else
void test()
{
    std::vector<S> vs;

    vs.push_back( S() );
    const S& s = vs.front();
    //S& s = vs.front(); // fine!
    S s1 = std::move(s); // Error, but expected
}
#endif
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Error:

```
1> error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory(1435) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'S &S::operator =(const S &)'
```

Comment: `'S &S::operator =(const S &)'` -- the compiler's not trying to call the copy *constructor* here... add a move assignment operator to your class.

Comment: Doh, that looks like an oversight! Too much code for me today! Thanks Xeo! How could I accept your comment as an answer? :D

Comment: I'm still a bit baffled that VS needs the assignment operator *at all* for the `count` constructor. It shouldn't do that.

Comment: Exactly! I was supposing based on fair reasoning that a move constructor would've suffice...

Comment: Not only that, the `count` constructor should just value construct (aka default construct) the objects, not even moving from anything...

Comment: Yep, the code compiles successfully on [GCC](http://liveworkspace.org/code/456bba52ee167d1cd97b92cf7e00c344) even with the copy / move constructors and both assignment operators deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in your std::lib.  I'm sure it got here because of the history of the evolving `vector` specification.

In C++98/03 `vector` had this constructor:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

And the specification was that the `T` would be default constructed once and then copy constructed `n` times when called with the latter two arguments defaulted.

In C++11 this got changed to:

```
explicit vector(size_type n);
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The spec for the 2nd constructor didn't change.  But the first did:  It should default construct `T n` times, and not copy (or move) it at all.

I would have expected the error message to say that the deleted or private **copy constructor** of `unique_ptr` was being used.  That would have indicated that the `vector` was following the C++98/03 spec, and simply hasn't been updated yet.

But since the diagnostic is complaining about `unique_ptr`'s **copy assignment** instead, then it looks like the `vector` has been updated, but incorrectly.  It sounds like it is using this signature from C++98/03:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

and default constructing `n` `T`'s, and then assigning `value` to those `n` `T`'s.

Comment: Very thorough analysis and explanation of the problem! Seems we are still living at the dawn of modern C++ era as far as Visual C++ is concerned. (the compiler I use to generate the error is Visual C++ 11 RC

Answer (score 0):

You did not include a move assignment operator, which is part of the `vector` requirements, only a move constructor.

Comment: I can not find this requirement for `vector`.  Can you give a section and paragraph number?